# What does the phrase "es schmeckt nach mehr" mean exactly and where did it come from?

Tags: english-to-german

My great-grandmother, who passed away around 1991 at the age of 96, used some German phrases that none of us could remember or understand. One of the phrases sounded like "Eshmeck nuck nock" (that's what it sounded like to me, I could be mistaken though). She always said this after dinner or lunch. As far as I recall, it means, "it was very tasty, can I have some more?" or "I liked it, one more time". Not sure about the exact meaning.

I am not looking for a simple translation, I am looking for a specific phrase, just one particular expression that people used to say around 1910-1915 because it was around that time that my great-grandmother got her education.

---

Update: it might be "es schmeckt nach mehr". What does it mean?

Comment: Could it have been "Das schmeckt nach mehr?"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. "Das schmeckt" sounds plausible. I don't remember "mehr" though. I thought it ended with a "noche", if I remember it correctly.

Comment: *Schmeckt nach noch einem [Teller voll]/noch einmal* would also be possible.

Comment: The Duden gives some nice examples for sayings: http://www.duden.de/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/schmecken
Even if it does not sound like this I would say it could be: "Es schmeckt nach mehr" but this is only a guess. This means the sayer is in hope there is more. Either immediately or later unspecified.

Comment: The phrase meant "tasty/delicious/ may I have more? or I want the second helping". It is a common saying, almost like a proverb or something. My grandma didn't invent it.

Comment: Yes, "es schmeckt nach mehr" sounds very close. At least closer to what she used to say than anything else.

Comment: I found this: Es schmeckt nach mehr ... wir kommen immer wieder. Is it some kind of a song?

Comment: No song, no nothing - just colloquial speak. I have found *Es schmeckt nach mehr* in a dictionary from 1810, so it's also quite old.

Comment: +1 for "Eshmeck nuck nock" :)

Comment: Where was she from (region, social background)?

Comment: if she was from a northern or hessian background, it could have been: "Es schmeckt nach noch". This would be slang or some dialect - "noch" can have the meaning of "more".

Comment: *willst du noch* as in *noch mehr*, *noch etwas*. *mehr* would be homophone with *Meer*, "the see", which makes sense, in a different context, or in a play of words on both words. *Es schmeckt nach noch mehr* would be a simple extension. However, this is exactly why I would reject a bare *nach noch*, @bukwyrm, It would sound incomplete. However, I can't exclude it either.

Answer (score 6):

> Es schmeckt nach mehr

is a colloquial expression you use when you really like some food or drink and ask for another helping.

It simply says "It tasted so good that I'd like to have some more".

*Camps Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache* (1810) says:

> *Das schmeckt nach mehr* sagt man im gemeinen Leben von einer Sache, welche so gut schmeckt, daß man mehr davon haben und genießen möchte.

So the expression has been around for some time and is still in good use today (as long as good food is near)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Even though I don't remember the exact phrase, it could be it.

Answer (score 6):

Wild guesses:

> Es schmeckt noch nach!

(I still have the taste in my mouth)

> Es schmeckt noch nach (...mehr)

(It tastes like (...wanting more of it))

Comment: Good point. Your first guess is phonetically quite close to what the OP remembered, while the second (already in tofro's answer) fits more to the supposed meaning.

Comment: The second one is ungrammatical in my opinion. *nach* is adverbial, not prepositional (I bet that's the correct PoS's).